# Jboss EAP 7 '@Management' and '@Service' Annotations

Tags: java, jboss, annotations, ejb-3.0, mbeans

Thinking of migration Old Jboss version ( 5 GA ) to new EAP 7 version we came across of below issues

- '@Service' Annotation was deprecated
- '@Management' Annotation not supported anymore.

Anyway we saw that '@Service' can be replaced with '@Singleton' ( EJB 3.1 spec) annotation.

But is there any way or workaround for '@Management' annotation ?

Thanks in advance.